# Lpsolve installing problems. OSX

Tags: php, macos, lpsolve

I'm trying to install lpsolve using this: http://jeyroz.tumblr.com/post/605709794/lpsolve-php
So, I'm trying to execute commands:

```
$ phpize
$ ./configure --enable-maintainer-zts --with-phplpsolve[version]=../..
$ make
$ make test
```

When I execute phpize, it says:

```
configure.in:3: warning: prefer named diversions
configure.in:3: warning: prefer named diversions
```

Not sure if this is normal.

When I execute `./configure --enable-maintainer-zts --with-phplpsolve55=../..`, it says:

```
WARNING: unrecognized options: --enable-maintainer-zts
and then there is some checking and error.
configure: error: Invalid phplpsolve55 library, make_lp() not found
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: I'm not sure, but try to `./configure` with `-enable-maintainer-zts` instead of `--enable-maintainer-zts`

Comment: I tried it, but mistake is the same. And warning too.

Answer (score 1):

the option, and corresponding error message, are totally confusing and make it look as though you first *need* the phplpsolve55 library in order to *build* the phplpsolve55 library.

but that is not the case here. it is instead looking for liblpsolve55.so:

```
checking lpsolve 5.5
  with-phplpsolve55=Insert path to lp_solve here            Include lpsolve Support... yes, shared
checking for make_lp in -llpsolve55... no
configure: error: Invalid phplpsolve55 library, make_lp() not found
```

the `--with-phplpsolve55=../..` option is telling `configure` where to find the header files; it needs to find the lpsolve library itself, `liblbsolve55.so`, in a trusted location. on Linux that would be /lib or /usr/lib; on Mac OSX, you may need to change the configure command to:

```
DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=../.. ./configure --enable-maintainer-zts --with-phplpsolve55=../..
```

for more information, see [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/282450/where-do-i-set-dyld-library-path-on-mac-os-x-and-is-it-a-good-idea).